Why is it often stated that Riccia has both type of rizhoids which are present attached to mid rib on the ventral surface of the thallus?
In liverworts, Phyllids lack midribs.
Then why is it often stated that Riccia has both type of rizhoids which are present attached to mid rib on the ventral surface of the thallus?

Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] to find out how this site works, and the help on asking good questions. It is important in a question that queries a common opinion that you quote an example. This both supports your assertion and allows others to inspect the source to see if it provides an explanation or has been taken out of context. I am not a botanist and know nothing whatever about this subject, but I think it would increase the likelihood of an answer from someone in this area.
